# How can I export a matlab figure as pdf/eps without loosing any part of the figure?

Tags: matlab-figure

How can I export a matlab figure as pdf/eps without loosing any part of the figure?
If I maximize the graphical window, I loose a part of the figure, if I minimize, I obtain a figure not filling all the space and if I save as jpg, I obtain a very well scaled figure, but with a bad resolution.

Answer (score 2):

You can control size of the figure on the paper using the `Position` property which is a vector `[left bottom width height]`. For example:

```
set(gcf,'Position',[0,0,560,900])
```

Then export the re-sized figure to pdf.